# R: using separate df for geom_text causes unwanted legend element

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend, geom-text

I have searched through all the available posts here related to this topic. I have this data frame with a row for "Other", I want to plot only the top 5 items and leave the others behind. Now I want to add a text to the plot to show the value for others.
My Idea: subset my df to plot the rows without "Other" and then use the df in geom_text to get those values. My Column "K" has factors and K_Subset only has 5 levels (excluding Other)
My Issue: The order of legend gets disrupted as soon as I add geom_text layer and "other" ends up being in the legend.
What I've tried: show.legend in geom_text aes,but it didn't work.

```
plot_K <-ggplot(data=K_subset, aes(x= K, y=T, fill=K)) +
  geom_bar(width=0.5,stat="identity") +
  labs(title = "Top 5", x = "K", y = "T")+
  geom_text(aes(label = T), 
            position = position_dodge(width=1), vjust =-0.5, size=4)+
  geom_text(data= K_import, aes(label = paste("T=", sum(Ts)),
                y = 175, x = "S"), colour="black", size = 5)+
  geom_text(data=K_import, aes(label = paste("Other=", T[K=="Other"]),
                y = 165, x = "S"), colour="black", size = 5)
plot_K
```

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: can you give a reproducible example?

Comment: Hi, you can take K_import as a table with col K(A,B,C,D,E,Other) and col T(9,7,6,5,4,8) and K_subset would then be K_import without the last row (Other,8)